# How to download multiple files from R/Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

There are a number of different Q/A's regarding this topic on SO, but none that I have been able to find that fit my use-case. I am also very surprised that RStudio / the Shiny developers themselves have not come out with some documentation on how to do this. Regardless, take this example application:

```
library(shiny)
library(glue)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test Multi-File Download"),
    p("I hope this works!"),
    downloadButton(
        outputId = "download_btn",
        label = "Download",
        icon = icon("file-download")
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    #datasets stored in reactiveValues list
    to_download <- reactiveValues(dataset1 = iris, dataset2 = airquality, dataset3 = mtcars, dataset4 = NULL)
    blahblah <- iris
    
    output$download_btn <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function(){
            paste("my_data_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file){
            
           #works
           #readr::write_csv(blahblah, file)
 
                
            #Attempt 1
           #  #create some temp directory
           #  temp_directory <- tempdir()
           # browser()
           #   reactiveValuesToList(to_download) %>%
           #       #x is data, y is name
           #      imap(function(x,y){
           #          #browser()
           #          #check if data is not null
           #          if(!is.null(x)){
           #              #create file name based on name of dataset
           #              file_name <- glue("{y}_data.csv")
           #              #write file to temp directory
           #              readr::write_csv(x, file_name)
           #          }
           #      })
            
            # zip::zip(
            #     zipfile = file,
            #     files = ls(temp_directory),
            #     root = temp_directory
            # )

        }
        
    )

    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have some datasets that are stored in a `reactiveValues` list, and I would like the user to be able to download them all. Ideally, I'd like for them just to be able to download multiple files all at once, rather than having to `zip` them up, and then download a `.zip` file. Another option I would be okay with is to add each dataset to an Excel sheet, then download the multi-sheet Excel file.
My general thought process (on the former) is as follows:

1. Download button gets pressed
2. create some temporary directory
3. write (the not `NULL`) datasets contained in `to_download` reactiveValues list to this directory
4. `zip` the temp directory and download

I feel like I am very close, however I have not been able to successfully get this work yet. Any ideas?

Edit 1: I am aware of the proposed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916535/download-multiple-csv-files-with-one-button-downloadhandler-with-r-shiny), but would like to avoid using `setwd()` because I believe it is bad practice to mess with working directories from within a Shiny application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download multiple csv files with one button (downloadhandler) with R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916535/download-multiple-csv-files-with-one-button-downloadhandler-with-r-shiny)

Comment: @NelsonGon I have read through this question, and it seems to me (very) bad practice to use `setwd()` within a Shiny app. I would like to avoid this if at all possible.

Comment: For the multi_excel (ah, I am stuck in tidyverse_syntax) sheet, I think you can loop through reactiveVals on button click and write to sheet with openxl(sx) or some other excel writer.

Comment: @NelsonGon Yes, I had tried that (using `writexl::write_xlsx()`) in a similar way to how I have commented out, inside an `imap()`, but was unsuccessful with then providing some conditional to test whether data is `NULL` or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things edited and it's working:

- using `dir` instead of `ls` inside the `zip::zip` call to show the contents of the temp directory (`ls` lists R environment rather than directory contents)
- as a further suggestion: making a new, unique folder inside `tempdir()` to ensure only relevant files are added.

```r
library(shiny)
library(glue)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Test Multi-File Download"),
  p("I hope this works!"),
  downloadButton(
    outputId = "download_btn",
    label = "Download",
    icon = icon("file-download")
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #datasets stored in reactiveValues list
  to_download <- reactiveValues(dataset1 = iris, dataset2 = airquality, dataset3 = mtcars, dataset4 = NULL)
  blahblah <- iris
  
  output$download_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste("my_data_", Sys.Date(), ".zip", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file){
      
       temp_directory <- file.path(tempdir(), as.integer(Sys.time()))
       dir.create(temp_directory)
       
        reactiveValuesToList(to_download) %>%
           imap(function(x,y){
               if(!is.null(x)){
                   file_name <- glue("{y}_data.csv")
                   readr::write_csv(x, file.path(temp_directory, file_name))
               }
           })
        
      
      zip::zip(
          zipfile = file,
          files = dir(temp_directory),
          root = temp_directory
      )
      
      

    },
    contentType = "application/zip"
    
  )
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[In my own Shiny app](https://github.com/andrewbaxter439/ITS_shinyapp/blob/master/server.R#L127) I had used a multi-worksheet approach as you suggested above. An alternative setup which works to produce a multi-sheet xlsx workbook using `openxlsx` could be:

```
...

output$download_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste("my_data_", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file){
      
       wb <- createWorkbook()
       
        reactiveValuesToList(to_download) %>%
           imap(function(x,y){
               if(!is.null(x)){
                 addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = y)
                 writeData(wb, x, sheet = y)
               }
           })
        
        saveWorkbook(wb, file = file)
    },
    contentType = "file/xlsx"
    
  )

...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help, Andy! I appreciate it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity Andy, do you have any insight on how this could be refactored to not need to `zip` ? i.e., just download 3 files at once?

Comment: hmm that's a good question, and I think outwith the bounds of normal shiny tools to do ([download handler takes one file](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/main/R/shiny.R#L2001)). You could perhaps make a button manually to prompt it via some [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked)? I wonder if it's a little rude in internet etiquette to do so though :P

Comment: FWIW - I quite like your `zip` method here, might make a mental note of that as a tool for future apps!

Comment: Yeah, agreed. `zip` it is then! Thanks again for the help, and appreciate the compliment.